# loop for print number 1 to 50 no print 10 and 20 and 30 and 40 and 50

Tags: loops, for-loop

I want the for loop print  number 1 to 50, but without this number (10,20,30,40,50)

For example

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
21
22
.
.
.
.
.
99

Thanks

Comment: What language? This should be trivial to google for, search for modulus functions.

Comment: And what problem? And how is 99 within 1...50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple for loop with a if statment in c#

```
 for(int i=0;1<50;i++)
 {
      if(i%10!=0)
      {
           console.Write(i+" ");
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is in C#.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 50; i++){
 if(i % 10 != 0){
    Console.Write(i);
    Console.Write(" ");
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In python:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    if i % 10 != 0:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

In PHP

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 10 !== 0) {
        echo $i . " ";
    }
}
```

The part that you're interested in is the `modulus` operator, or the `%`. What this does, is it returns the **remainder** of two numbers. So, 11 % 10 has a remainder of 1, but 20 % 0 has a remainder of 0. So we can use this to find out if a number is divisible by 10 or not

Answer (score -2):

int i=100;

```
    for(i=1;i<=200;i++)
{
  if(i<=30)
  {
       System.out.println(i+" ");
  }
}     
    for(i=31;i<=100;i++)
    {
        if(i<=60)
        {
            System.out.println(i +" ");
        }
    }
```